# Getting Access Denied on reading and writing txt file from Root Folder

Tags: windows, maui, maui-blazor, .net-maui, maui-windows

I am trying to read .txt file in Maui Program from the location which I am getting from
*Path.GetPathRoot(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal));*

I am getting access denied error.

What permissions have to give to the windows application.

Answer (score 0):

Reading system root files requires administrator privileges

1. Run Visual Studio as administrator.
2. In solution explorer, add new item, select "Application Manifest File".

change

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

to

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```